# how to fix div button to right of screen?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-position, fixed

I have a div button consisting two piece div and a parent div. The button must be in right of side on screen. But it does not stay still When changing screen resolution(Ex; 100% ,%75)

[image]

parent div css:

```
.help-parent{
    position: "absolute";
    top:"0px";
}
```

help icon css :

```
.help {
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(243, 77, 0);
     display:inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    top: 50px;
    left: 1490px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 11;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

second div :

```
.help-button {
    position: absolute;
    text-align:left;
    top:50px;
    background-color:rgb(243, 77, 0);
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:31px;
    z-index: 10;
    left:1500px;
}
```

When change screen resolution %100 to %75 it slides left;

[image]

I want the button to stay in the fixed position. How can I achive this?

I have modified according to answer of @greg_. I removed absolute from child divs and I have added vw 95 and absolute position to parent div. And div is fixed to righ. After I removed absoulute from child divs separated from each other. How can I combine child divs ?

[image]

Comment: You are using a fixed value on 'left' you can use right: 0; to make it stick to the right. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child divs should move with the parent, so remove any position css for the child divs.
For the parent, try using viewport units (vh, vw). This will ensure that the position is always relative to the viewport.
Parent div css:

```css
.help-parent {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:95vw;
}
```

1vw = 1% of the viewport width, so 95vw will keep your button at 95% the viewport width (far right).
more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer , I have modified according to your advice. Parent div is fixed to right. this is good news. But Child divs have separated from each other when I removed position:absoulte from child divs. How can I combine them? I m adding image end of the post

Comment: Try adding a fixed width to the parent div. This can also be viewport specific. eg. `width: 10vw`.

Answer (score 0):

I beleave, you have to think more about   `left`.

Answer (score 0):

You added a fixed `left` value. Use `right` instead or `left: 90xw`

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting about the importance of the `position` and what it does related to a parent element.

Absolute only applies to the parent if the parent `position` is also set to either `relative` or `fixed` etc.

I made an example below on how it could work.

**More about CSS positions:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
/* container to set a base line */
.menu-bar {
  position: fixed; /* fixed to the viewport */
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0; /* set to top of viewport */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* not question related styling */
  background: #fff;
}

/* set elements to stick within it's parent element */

.stick {
  position: absolute; /* stick to current parent */
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0; /* stick to top of parent */
  /* not question related styling */
  background: red;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -50px; /* negative to go beyond the viewport */
  /* not question related styling */
  text-align: right;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -50px; /* negative to go beyond the viewport */
}

.left:hover {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.right:hover {
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-bar">
  <span class="stick left">Left</span>
  <span class="stick right">right</span>
</nav>
<main>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et laoreet tellus. Vivamus iaculis dui quis blandit porttitor. Morbi egestas turpis eget maximus porttitor. Phasellus a neque imperdiet, mattis tortor a, convallis tellus. Aenean dignissim at lectus ut varius. Nam a mauris ut magna mollis blandit vel at erat. Quisque in velit bibendum, rhoncus lorem vitae, aliquet nulla. Sed nulla magna, ultricies ac egestas et, bibendum quis enim. Nunc cursus gravida sapien in blandit. Duis dignissim nunc quis finibus dictum. Etiam laoreet, felis in aliquam gravida, lectus nulla vestibulum turpis, in porttitor ligula mi nec risus. Cras vitae augue lectus. In et ligula sapien. Pellentesque lacus erat, ornare sit amet metus id, sollicitudin bibendum purus. Proin in elit metus.

Aenean elementum scelerisque ante, eget vulputate justo interdum quis. Duis luctus tortor bibendum felis dignissim suscipit. Curabitur egestas lectus ut ligula gravida, non aliquet odio auctor. Aliquam placerat, mi at consectetur euismod, nunc quam congue velit, et lacinia purus risus vel arcu. Vestibulum in nisl sed sem rutrum dictum. Quisque egestas porta tortor varius elementum. Duis hendrerit risus sit amet metus commodo pulvinar a a lorem. Nulla facilisis dapibus magna in cursus.

Proin imperdiet sollicitudin nisi consectetur mattis. Fusce euismod neque eu orci interdum, dapibus fringilla libero vestibulum. Nam sed dignissim lectus. Aenean lacus ante, scelerisque vitae viverra eget, vehicula imperdiet purus. Nam ut metus vitae lacus pellentesque imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. In tristique justo sit amet tellus consectetur, id consequat sapien sollicitudin. Curabitur tincidunt neque nibh, ut pharetra tellus maximus cursus. Nullam ac enim lacus. In sed quam a metus venenatis pharetra. Ut placerat quam vitae purus luctus, ac tempor massa volutpat. Mauris dignissim a eros sit amet vehicula.</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right for simple buttons. But when you rotate the button it won't work. So the logic is in the problem. Situation is we need to fix a button to the right side of page with a 90deg rotation.
What happens is the button get sticks to the right side but with some space from the right side.
What is that space?
That space is half of the width of the element (Without rotation).
i.e;
let the width of the element be (***w***), Height be(***h***) and right spacing as (***s***)

***s* = (*w*/2)**

Now here one interesting thing happens, when you rotate and apply this rule half of the button is hidden. Why? this is because when you rotate the button the ***s*** includes half of the height ***h*** of the button. The half yellow dotted line in the image.

[image: Visualisation]
So the ***s*** we need is

***s* = (*w*/2) - (*h*/2)**

Solution: give the button/ section / div a width. This is the element that you need to hang on the right.
Then rotate it and add a right(***r***) with ***s* px**

```css
.wharf{
    display: flex;
    width:159px;
    height: 39px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #1457AE;
    color:#fff;
}

.flotter-wharf {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    rotate: -90deg;
    z-index: 999;
    right: -60px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 159px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flotter-wharf">
    <div calss="row">
        <a href="#" class="wharf">Click me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```